# Scoreboard Command isn't being shown

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I did the score board command correct but i cant get the scoreboard to show.

```
/scoreboard objectives add Health trigger Health
```

then

```
/scoreboard players set SuperFlyingWoody Health 0
```

but i still cant see the scoreboard,
can someone help me please?

Answer (score 2):

To see a scoreboard, use the `scoreboard objectives setdisplay` command. Most common:

```
/scoreboard objectives setdisplay sidebar Health
```

Comment: you need to put the Objective Name to display, not the name of the player.

Comment: Oh, right, the names confused me. Btw, you can also edit that yourself, I'll see it then.

Comment: Right, I forgot about that. I'm not that frequent on here. Will do that in the future

Answer (score 0):

The reason is not working is because you are trying to show the health the scoreboard objective is put like this:

```
/scoreboard objective add health health
```

then:

```
/scoreboard objective setdisplay {sidebar/list/belowName} health
```